# Pylint on VS Code with WSL2: Unable to import local packages (import-error)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

Context:

- Windows 10 + VS Code + WSL2
- WSL2 using Ubuntu 20.04 and all the dev environment is installed inside the distro
- On the distro I use pyenv to create a virtual environment
- My workspace has a project with sub-projects folder structure, I need to configure pylint for one specific sub-project
- I'm using python 3.10 and have already installed pylint in the virtual environment
- Virtual environment folder is under `~/venvs/virtualenv`
- I've already selected the python interpreter on VS Code pointing to `~/venvs/virtualenv` python binary

Folder structure:

```
main_project/
| .vscode/
| | settings.json <----- B
| sub_projects/
| | proj_1/
| | proj_2/
| | | src/
| | | | app/
| | | | | __init__.py 
| | | | | api/
| | | | | | rest/
| | | | | | | __init__.py <--- A
| | | | | services/
| | | | | | __init__.py
| | | | | | database.py
```

The problem I have:

- the code runs without problems, but pylint complains about the following import in `A`:
  `from app.services import database`
- The error is `Unable to import 'app.services' pylint(import-error)`

These are my current settings.json file (B on the tree):

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    },
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
}
```

**Question**
How should I configure `settings.json` to make pylint recognize the import?
Besides the code running, even the autocomplete is working, which shows that the python interpreter is properly set, so the problem seems to be pylint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vscode identification file is found with the workspace as the root directory. You can use the following methods to import method:

1. Use code `from sub_projects.proj_2.src.app.services import database`
2. Place a .env file at the root of your project which adds your source directory to PYTHONPATH:

   PYTHONPATH=/sub_projects/proj_2/src/

Tips:
You can add the following code to your **settings.json**, you can also change the file name here.

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env" // for example "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/dev.env"
```

Comment: "Vscode identification file is found with the workspace as the root directory" is the key information here, that wasn't clear for me, thanks. Solution 2 removed pylint import errors. Is there a way to use a different file name other than ".env"? Sometimes it confuses with my docker ".env" files.

Comment: This sentence means that no matter where the file you run is in the workspace, the workspace is always the root directory, not the folder where the file runs. At the same time, I updated my answer. Of course, you can customize the file name. Reading [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file) for more details is also a good choice